# JQuery Datepicker selecting disabled date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a JQuery datepicker where I set the default date to be today's date +15 days.
I also made it so that the user can't select a date that falls on the weekend.  However, when I implement the following code, it allows the disabled weekend date to be selected.
Question: How can I make it so that it picks the next available date?

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
  $.datepicker.regional["fi-FI"]);

$('.datepicker').wijtextbox().datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', +15);
```

The above code defaults to October 10, which is a Saturday, which is disabled.  How do I get it to pick the next available date, which would be Monday, October 12?

Comment: You won't be able to use `noWeekends`, which obviously disables those dates. You'll have to write a custom function (possibly incorporating `noWeekends()` to detect weekend days) and shift the date returned.

Answer (score 2):

Before you use `setDate`, check if your arbitrary value of 15 produces a `Sat.` Or `Sun.` and if so add 1 or 2 more to the `setDate`

```
const mydate = new Date();
mydate.setDate(mydate.getDate() + 15);

if(mydate.getDay() == 6){ //Sat. add 2 more days
   $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', +17);
} else if(myDate.getDay() == 0){ //Sun add 1 more day
   $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', +16);
}else{
   $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', +15);
}
```